# Libfuzzer target for on-disk parsing

Tags: fuzzing, libfuzzer

I'm currently integrating `libFuzzer` in a project which parses files on the hard drive. I have some prior experience with AFL, where a command line like this one was used:

```
afl-fuzz -m500 -i input/ -o output/ -t100 -- program_to_fuzz @@
```

...where `@@` was a path to the generated input.
Looking at `libFuzzer` however, I see that the fuzz targets look like this:

```
extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t *Data, size_t Size) {
  DoSomethingInterestingWithMyAPI(Data, Size);
  return 0;  // Non-zero return values are reserved for future use.
}
```

I understand that the input isn't provided in the form of a file, but as a buffer in-memory instead. The problem is that the program I'm trying to fuzz works with files and obtains its data through `fread()` calls. At no point in time is the whole input supposed to be loaded in memory (where, in the general case, it might not even fit); so there's not much I can do with a `const uint8_t*`.

Writing the buffer back to the hard drive to get back a file seems extremely inefficient. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Maybe a file on a `tmpfs` would help (in case of Linux -- it is a RAM disk, so no writing to underlying disk, but still some fs syscall overhead...). Next, you could `mmap` this file and then `memcpy` data into it, but not sure how to handle the file size properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as in [this example](https://github.com/google/security-research-pocs/blob/649b6ed74c842f533d15410f13d94aada96375ef/autofuzz/alembic_fuzzer.cc#L299) from google security team. 
The buf_to_file defined [here](https://github.com/google/security-research-pocs/blob/master/autofuzz/fuzz_utils.cc#L42-L78) takes your buffer and returns a char* pathname you can then pass to you target:
(from https://github.com/google/security-research-pocs/blob/master/autofuzz/fuzz_utils.h#L27 )

```
// Write the data provided in buf to a new temporary file. This function is  
// meant to be called by LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput() for fuzz targets that only  
// take file names (and not data) as input.  
//  
// Return the path of the newly created file or NULL on error. The caller should  
// eventually free the returned buffer (see delete_file).   
extern "C" char *buf_to_file(const uint8_t *buf, size_t size);
```

Be sure to free the ressource with the [delete_file](https://github.com/google/security-research-pocs/blob/master/autofuzz/fuzz_utils.cc#L31) function.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow! While this answer maybe helpful, links to third-party websites can become invalid over time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LD_PRELOAD and override fread.